# PHP / HTML - Generate a html list from a array

Tags: php, html, arrays, html-lists

I have a array like `('mary', 'johnny', 'butch', 'pony', 'katy', 'chuck', 'norris')`
The number of elements can vary...

How can I build a nice list from all these elements, like this:

```
<ul>
  <li>
    Mary
    Johnny
    Butch
  </li>

  <li>
    Pony
    Katy
  </li>

  <li>
    Chuck
    Norris
  </li>
```

?

Basically build the list like a spiral:

```
> -------------
               |
<--------------
|
>--------------
               |
<--------------
```

The number of list items is fixed, for eg. 3 in the example above

Comment: What rules are being followed here? How will the script know when to use three, and when to use two elements?

Comment: array_chunk would give you 3-3-1 instead of 3-2-2, is that acceptable?

Comment: pekka I forgot to mention that there are 3 list items. I want to distribute the array elements evenly to these 3 `<li>`'s

Comment: But what if there are more than 9 elements in the array?

Comment: oops, my mistake max 3 items per list is wrong - I meant max 3 list items :)

Comment: ok. nevermind. I found a function that does this on the array_chunk function help page - http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php#75022

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yet Another Path, Because There Was Not Weird Enough Code Posted.

```
//set the amount of items
$li_items = 3;//can be anything, really

echo '<ul>';
//loop
for(;$li_items > 0;$li_items--){
   echo "\n\t<li>\n\t".implode("\n\t",
       array_splice($array,0,ceil(count($array)/$li_items))
      )."\n\t<li>";
}
echo '</ul>';
```

Comment: lol, thanks. but I'll go with the partition() function I found :)

Comment: That function _does_ have the advantage of being legible indeed ;)

Answer (score 2):

You want to group them in 3's? Something like:

```
<?php
$list = ('mary', 'johnny', 'butch', 'pony', 'katy', 'chuck', 'norris');
$c = 0;
$LIMIT = 3;
echo "<ul>";
foreach($list as $current) {
    echo "<li>$current</li>";
    $c += 1;
    if($c == $LIMIT) { echo "</ul><ul>"; }
}
echo "</ul>";
```

Very ugly, but gets the job done

Comment: I think Alex is looking for a script that will shift as more are added.  So if there's 12, he wants groups of 4, 9 would be groups of three, etc.  The hitch comes when you have non-divisible numbers, which would probably require everybody's favorite, the ceil command

Comment: exactly :)
the example above shows one group of 3 and two groups of 2.

Comment: This is not an advisable snippet because: 1. It introduces a temporary variable that could have been incremented by the foreach 2. `$c === 3` only occurs once, but needs to occur over and over (every three iterations).

Answer (score 1):

What you should do is separate *presentation* from *logic*.  Instead of figuring out how many items should go in each element, put each item in it's own element.  Each one is a line-item after all.

```
<ul class="the_list">
    <li>Mary</li>
    <li>Johnny</li>
    <li>Butch</li>
    <li>Pony</li>
    <li>Katy</li>
    <li>Chuck</li>
    <li>Norris</li>
</ul>
```

Then use CSS to display the list however you want.  For example, you could do something like this:

```
.the_list    { width:300px;}
.the_list li { display:block;float:left;width:100px;}
```

You'll need some additional rules like a reset stylesheet first, but that's the gist of it.

Comment: thanks, but in my case it's not possible because I'm applying this to a graphic slider. Number of list items are fixed, and only 3 items are displayed at a time. the rest will slide...

Comment: What is this graphic slider you mention?  Can it not be edited?

Comment: actually there are 3 such sliders applied to each of the 3 `<li>`'s. This is why I need them separated. the slider is the "cycle" jquery plugin

Answer (score 1):

You could loop through the array and use modulus

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($array); $i++)
{
    if ($i % 3 == 0)
    {
        //append to first li
    }
    else if ($i % 3 == 1)
    {
        //append to second li
    }
    else
    {
        //append to third li
    }
}
```